# Modx как выбрать предыдущую и следующею статью по дате

Tags: php, sql, modx

Нужно выбрать из базы alias предыдущей и следующей записи по дате.
Дата публикации хранится в секундах.

```
        case "OnLoadWebDocument": 

        $postlink = explode('/',$_GET['q']);

        $thispost = $modx->db->getValue($modx->db->query("SELECT pub_date FROM `modx_site_content` WHERE parent=5 AND alias='$postlink[1]'")); 

        $posts = $modx->db->query("SELECT alias, pub_date FROM `modx_site_content` WHERE parent=5 ORDER BY pub_date");

        foreach($posts as $post){


            if($post['pub_date'] == $thispost){



            }else{



            }


    }
break;
```

Comment: А БД какая, MySQL ? Может одним запросом придумать ... я правда пока еще не придумал как :) И там записей с parent=5 много ?

Comment: Записей пока мало. В планах не более 2 тыс. Бд mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Традиционный способ: получаем дату текущей публикации в переменной $thispost и делаем что то вроде:

```
select * from (
   select alias, pub_date from modx_site_content
    where pub_date>=$thispost and parent=5
    order by pub_date
    limit 2
) A
union all
select * from (
   select alias, pub_date from modx_site_content
    where pub_date<$thispost and parent=5
    order by pub_date desc
    limit 1
) A
order by pub_date
```

Метод с переменными MySQL (мне кажется короче и теоретически быстрее, т.к. сортировка только одна): Заранее дату не получаем, а сразу получаем требуемые строки и узнаем "текущую" по порядковому номеру

```
  select @cur_num as cur_num, alias, pub_date, num
    from (
      select alias, pub_date, @num:=@num+1 num,
             @cur_num:=if(alias='$postlink[1]',@num,@cur_num)
        from modx_site_content C,
             (select @num:=0,@cur_num:=0) A
       where parent=5
       order by pub_date
    ) A
 where A.num between @cur_num-1 and @cur_num+1
```

В цикле чтения из запроса текущая запись находится как `if($post['num']==$post['cur_num'])`. Фокус запроса в том, что сначала MySQL выполняет внутренний подзапрос и после начинает обработку во внешнем запросе. При этом переменная @cur_num оказывается равной порядковому номеру записи с нужным нам *alias*, остается взять записи с номерами на 1 меньше и 1 больше "текущей".